# DateTime value passing incorrectly from javascript to C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using the below code to make call to the controller

```
DateFrom: moment.utc($(".datefrom").val(), "DD/MM/YYYY").toString()
```

in the ajax call I had a breakpoint and checked what is being passed and the value was

```
"Wed Jun 20 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000"
```

But when I check it in the C#, this is what is getting passed

[image]

Other values are getting passed correctly, but this DateFrom has an issue

I checked both the property names and they are exactly the same.

What am I missing?

Comment: Always serialize datetime values using [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) notation. Most libraries, including momentjs, have built in methods for converting a datetime instance to ISO8601 string and for parsing them (no additional call needed for momentjs when parsing, the constructor will handle it without additional input)

Comment: Never use ambiguous formats when passing dates around. Much safer to use something like `YYYY/MM/DD` or even better ISO8601 for example. What is the return value of `moment.utc()` here?

Comment: Does `$` in your JS code stand for jQuery?

Comment: you get `DateTime.MinValue`, so nothing is passed at all. could you show more of the relevant code, the ajax call and declaration and assignment of the target variable?

Comment: the value of the DateFrom was "Wed Jun 20 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000".

Comment: What happens if you don't include the `.toString()` call?

Comment: @Igor Thanks, that worked so I changed moment.utc to moment().toISOString() and it works. Please add it as answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always serialize DateTime values using [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) notation. Most libraries, including momentjs, have built in methods for converting a datetime instance to an [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string and for parsing them from an [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) back to a datetime instance (no additional call needed for momentjs when parsing, the constructor will handle it without additional input).

Keep in mind this is a separate concern from displaying the value on screen. The display and/or edit value should be localized for the user doing the viewing/entry. The serialized value is the value as it is sent between tiers or devices.

Answer (score 1):

This is because javascript use dates as milliseconds since 1970-01-01 and c# 01/01/1900 so in milliseconds there are a big difference.

I suggest you change your string format to **dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss**.

The best way is converting your date in javascript to a string that c# can recognize.

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();       // yields date
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;    // yields month (add one as '.getMonth()' is zero indexed)
var year = date.getFullYear();  // yields year
var hour = date.getHours();     // yields hours 
var minute = date.getMinutes(); // yields minutes
var second = date.getSeconds(); // yields seconds
var data= day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
```

After that send the "data" to your controller in C#

```
DateTime date=DateTime.ParseExact(data, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```